# Is there any shortcut to select a link in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I'd like to change in a quick way the image link, without clicking and drag the slider:

```
    <script>
    var app = new Vue({
        el:'#app',
        data:{
            product:'Pizza',
            description:'Pizza al royal per poco costo',
            image:'https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.englishclub.com%2Fimages%2Fvocabulary%2Ffood%2Fitalian%2Fmargherita-pizza.jpg&f=1&nofb=1'
            },
        })
</script>
```

Comment: If you're using Windows, you can always put the caret at the beginning of the link and press `Shift+End`. It will also get the last ', but you can just go `Shift + Left Arrow` afterwards. Fast enough for me, might work for you.

Comment: with [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) you can create a shortcut to select everything between `'`